# Why this TAD is returning 0.0000 instead of the result of the functions involved?

Tags: c++

I've coded this little program in order to pass an exam. It involves abstract type data in a language called C+-, wich is a limited version of C++. It is used in my university in order to provide a small language helpful to learn and to correct, with no so many possibilities as C++ has.

```
#include <stdio.h>


//Definimos una estructura, casi una clase, que contiene lo siguiente
typedef struct Calculadora
{
    //procesos
    float Sumar(float a, float b);
    float Restar(float a, float b);

  //variables

  private:

    float a;
    float b;
    float resultado;

};
// Fin de declaración de la estructura
// Declaración de los tipos de datos de la estructura

float Calculadora::Sumar(float a, float b)  // Así declaramos las funciones de una estructura
{

    resultado = a + b;
    return (resultado);
}

float Calculadora::Restar(float a, float b)  // Así declaramos las funciones de una estructura
{

    resultado = a - b;
    return (resultado);
}

// FIN DE LA DECLARACION DE TIPOS DE DATOS Y FUNCIONES DE LA ESTRUCTURA



int main()
{
float resultado,a,b;

printf("Introduce aquí los valores de la primera variable");
scanf("%f",&a);
printf("Introduce aquí los valores de la segunda variable");
scanf("%f",&b);

   Calculadora cal;
   cal.Sumar(a,b);

   printf("El resultado es %f", resultado);
}
```

But, the result is always 0.00000 That's not what the program aim for. Any idea on what could be wrong with this code?

Comment: `resultado = cal.Sumar(a,b);`

Comment: So this isn't C++? This is an in-house programming language?

Comment: Yes. it's called C+- and nobody knows it outside my University. I guess is something educative only to make teacher's life easier and away from real life problems ;P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing out the local variable `resultado` which is uninitialised in function `main()`

What you might want to do is to print out the **member variable** in `Calculadora` using a member function.

The result from `cal.Sumar(a,b);` is being discarded, in this case you must assign the result to a local variable in your main function if you want to store the result.

Comment: You can't _get_ at the member variable from `main()`, it's private. In fact the entire idea of storing the result into a member variable is ludicrous to begin with, since the result is returned to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

```
float Calculadora::Sumar(float a, float b) { ...
```

indicates that the function returns a value, yet you call it with:

```
cal.Sumar(a,b);
```

effectively (assuming your `C+-` language is like C) throwing away the result.

You shoulkd be *storing* the result to print it out:

```
resultado = cal.Sumar(a,b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the solution was obvious (only when someone pointed out the silly mistake present in the code).

resultado = calc.Sumar(a,b);

Thanks!